# Passing options to biber through latexmk

Tags: biber, latexmk

According to the man page for `latexmk` there is a command line option `-latexoption=<option>` for passing options to `pdflatex`, but there seems to be no similar way to pass options to `biber`.

Is there a way to pass options such as `--validate-datamodel` or `--isbn-normalise` to `biber` while using `latexmk`?

Comment: In `~/.latexmkrc`, add `$biber='biber --validate-datamodel %O %S'` (or whatever options you like).

Comment: @Derek: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Please make it an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Glad that helped!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `~/.latexmkrc`, add `$biber='biber --validate-datamodel %O %S'` (or whatever options you like)

Comment: If I understand correctly a `;` at the end of each command is needed, at least if there is more than one in `.latexmkrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into an issue where I'm running latexmk from a build script and do not want the user to have to modify their ~/.latexmkrc file. For this, the options can be provided on the command line without changing the user's environment:

```
latexmk -e '$biber='"'"'biber --isbn-normalise %O %S'"'" [your_tex_file]
```