# How to pass arguments to biber in TextMate?

Tags: biber, textmate

Is there a way to pass arguments to biber in TextMate: either as a configuration option or as a directive similar to the %!TEX TS-options for LaTex? Or do I need  to rely on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that you enabled `Use LaTeXmK` inside `Bundles`→`LaTeX`→`Preferences`

[image: LaTeX Bundle - Preferences]

2. Follow the steps provided by Derek in [this StackExchange thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331504/passing-options-to-biber-through-latexmk):

   1. Create the file `~/.latexmkrc` (`~` is the name of your home folder)
   2. Insert the line `$biber='biber --validate-datamodel %O %S'` in `~/.latexmkrc`
   3. Modify the line above to your liking
   4. If you want to use specific biber options for a specific project, then a `.latexmkrc` file inside the same folder as your main LaTeX file should work too.