# Using latexmk in combination with biber --isbn-normalise

Tags: biber, latexmk

How can I combine using `latexmk` with `biber --isbn-normalise`?

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331508/36296 I tried to add

```
$biber='biber --isbn-normalise %O %S'
```

to `.latexmkrc` but this resulted in the following error:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at (eval 7) line 2, near "1
$biber"
    (Missing operator before 
$biber?)
Latexmk: Initialization file '/Users/<username>/.latexmkrc' gave an error:
     syntax error at (eval 7) line 2, near "1
     $biber"

Latexmk: Stopping because of problem with rc file
```

I am using `biber version: 2.8 (beta)`

---

My use case is to have this for one file, so adding some option to the call of `latexmk -<some_magick_option> %` or `\usepackage[some_magick_option]{biblatex}` would be fine, it does not have to be globally set in the `.latexmkrc` file.

Comment: Aren't you missing a ; at the end of that line? (Perl syntax)

Comment: You can add it in an rc file can call it via `-r myconf.rc` the syntax is the same as for latexmkrc but is just not global. I think the cited page is in error, since the confs are al Perl variable specifications, the specification should end with a semi colon

Comment: @daleif Thank you so much! The `;` solves my problem and the config file is a very good idea. Can you please convert your first comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latexmk is written in Perl. Thus an assignment like this should be ended with a ;

Additionally you can run a local version of latexmkrc via the `-r <filename>` option, handy for setting that are only needed for a single project

My guess is that the cited question is misleading because it is missing the trailing semi colons