# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character'(\U+0301) error

Tags: biblatex, pdftex

I am getting the following error in my project while using this [template](https://github.com/GarenSidonius/ASU-Dissertation-Template).

[image]

Despite the error, my pdf is rendering fine. Should I worry about the error even though I do not see the unicode character in the line that the error is talking about?

Comment: Yes, you should worry about it. It probably has to do with `\'\i` or `\'{\i}` in your `.bib` file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469555/35864 and linked posts.

Comment: yes, there are these characters in my bib. should i remove them, or escape the?

Comment: author       = {Freire, Manuel and Serrano-Laguna, {\'A}ngel and Manero, Borja and Mart{\'\i}nez-Ortiz, Iv{\'a}n and Moreno-Ger, Pablo and Fern{\'a}ndez-Manj{\'o}n, Baltasar}

Comment: i have this in my `.bib` file

Comment: As it says in the linked answer, the best solution is to use Unicode: `í` instead of `\'\i`. This can easily be arranged with a search-and-replace job. (Of course the same goes for the other accented characters.) So you would have `author = {Freire, Manuel and Serrano-Laguna, Ángel and Manero, Borja and Martínez-Ortiz, Iván and Moreno-Ger, Pablo and Fernández-Manjón, Baltasar}`

Comment: It worked by removing the escape characters. Much thanks :)