# How to display multiple authors in bibliography-NOT A DUPLICATE

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

This question is related to [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/192267)

I tried to do the same thing as listed in the solution of that solution. My problem is the same *How to put all the author names in the bibliography  if it is more than 5?*

I am attaching a basic working example so that someone can help me figure it out.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,authblk,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]     
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[section] 
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt][maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\date{}
\title{Title}
\author{}
\affil{}

\begin{document}
%   \maketitle
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        
                
    \end{abstract}
    
    \textbf{Keywords:} 
    \\
    \\
    \textbf{2010 Mathematics Subject Classification:} 
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{Sec1}
    
    \begin{example}
        This is an example.
    \end{example}
    
        \begin{note}
            This is a note.
        \end{note}
    
    \begin{lemma}
        This is a lemma.
    \end{lemma}
     
     \begin{theorem}
        This is a theorem.
     \end{theorem}
 \begin{proof}
    This is a proof.
 \end{proof}
\begin{definition}
    This is a definition.
\end{definition}
        
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
line 17: Missing \begin{document}. \usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt][m
line 18: Undefined control sequence. \addbibresource
line 2: Undefined control sequence. \abx@aux@refcontext
line 2: Missing \begin{document}. \abx@aux@refcontext{a
line 3: Undefined control sequence. \abx@aux@refcontextdefaultsdone
line 64: Undefined control sequence. \printbibliography
line 34: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

**Will it be possible for someone here to please let me know why is TeXStudio not allowing me to compile the same?**
If someone can please help me out, I will be immensely grateful.

**EDIT:I tried the solution offered in the answer by @Mico**
Now I am getting another error. It reads:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ́ (U+0301)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (1.69928pt too wide) in paragraph
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\Gamma'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `subscript'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `subscript'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\Gamma'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `subscript'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `subscript'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Overfull \hbox (1.3403pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (1.21469pt too wide) in paragraph
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\Gamma'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `subscript'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `subscript'
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
Overfull \hbox (18.60725pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (32.27495pt too wide) detected
Overfull \hbox (2.67932pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (8.88283pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (13.32054pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Comment: The new error is completely different and cannot be reproduced with what the example code shows so far. (The most likely cause is a faulty `.bib` entry: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469555/35864 Don't use `{\'{\i}}` or `{\'\i}`, use `{\'i}` instead.)

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The avalanche of error messages is set off by the instruction on line 17:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt][maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

I think you want

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

A general suggestion: When trying to make sense of a slew of TeX error messages, it's crucial to focus on the very first error message. Even though the `Missing \begin{document}` component of the error message `line 17: Missing \begin{document}.  ...`  may not be the clearest possible indication of what has gone wrong, it should be a definite tip-off that something really isn't right on line 17.

---

*Addendum*: A related suggestion on how to learn to work with TeX's error message: *Do actually read the full error message.* E.g., you reported in your posting that the error message consisted of the single line

```
line 17: Missing \begin{document}. \usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt][m
```

However, the full error message actually is as follows:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.17 \usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt][m
                                               axbibnames=99]{biblatex}
?
```

It looks like you -- or maybe TeXstudio?? -- contracted the multi-line message into a single line by taking material from the first and penultimate lines. That's a shortcut not worth taking. Importantly and quite usefully (IMNSHO), TeX inserts a line break right where the error condition is set off. With just a bit of practice, you'll learn to infer that the error message is caused by a syntax error in your code, spot and fix the syntax error, and move on.

I don't use TeXstudio myself, but I've read elsewhere that in a misguided effort to help users, it actually makes error messages meaningless by stripping away crucial information. If you find that's the case for your TeX installation, you may want to think about moving on to a different frontend/editor, one which doesn't mess around with TeX's error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Your answers are always impressive, But now there is another problem, my TeX file is again showing error.

Comment: The error after doing the corrections you said reads like this "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ́ (U+0301)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX."

Comment: Can you please help me out ?

Comment: @Math_Freak - Please post a new query. Ideally, the code in the new query would be *minimal*, i.e., just enough to reproduce the issue(s) you need to fix.