# Wrong character written before usage of \DeclareUnicodeCharacter

Tags: biber, unicode, input-encodings

My bib file contains (the most famous book)

```
@book {Gohberg-Krein*69, AUTHOR = {Gohberg, I. C. and Kre{\u \i}n, M. G.},}
```

I'm using a usual `amsart` class and `biblatex` set with Biber and UTF-8. And my preamble has the command

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0306}{{\u \i}}
```

The result is something like: "Kre\i{\u\i}n". So a first i without dot is issued, then the proper {\u\i}.

Would anyone how to cure that? I understand next to nothing on encodings :/
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you prefer using ASCII escapes use `Kre{\u i}n` instead of `Kre{\u \i}n`. That said, if you are OK with using Unicode, use `Kreĭn` (as suggested by David).

Comment: @moewe although (as has been discussed before) `\u i` and `\u\i` not being treated the same way is definitely a biblatex and/or biber bug.

Comment: Accents on the i are a bit tricky in `biblatex`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469555/35864

Answer (score 2):

U+0306 is the combining breve accent not ĭ which is U+012D, it is not really possible to support combining characters with pdftex as they follow the base.

Make sure your input has the single character ĭ (U+012D) not the pair ı (U+0131) ̆ (U+0306)

The output you describe is consistent with the input U+0131 producing `\i` followed by U+0306 producing `\u\i` following your redefinition of the combining accent.

In the original bib file source you can use `ĭ` or `{\u i}` either of which which will generate the correct output.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!