# ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ̆ (U+0306)

Tags: unicode

since I try to include my literature I get the following unicode error: ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ̆ (U+0306)
what exactly does this mean and how can I solve this error? Can anyone help me?

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The most common LaTeX engine pdflatex isn't designed to handle Unicode. If you intend to use Unicode characters, you need to use a Unicode engine which is lualatex or xelatex.

Comment: you are using a combining accent which pdflatex can't handle. If you want to stick to pdflatex you will have to replace that by a suitable command.

Comment: [Crosspost in German](https://texwelt.de/fragen/29053/unicode-fehler-u0306)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong character written before usage of \DeclareUnicodeCharacter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624221/wrong-character-written-before-usage-of-declareunicodecharacter) Maybe the question is not absolutely the same, but the answer could nevertheless be useful for this question too.

Comment: Use single character eg Ă (U+0102) not A followed by U+0306