# biblatex issue: \DeclareUnicodeCharacter

Tags: biblatex

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18 (TeX Live 2017) to Ubuntu 20, and things broke:
I now need to add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0304}{ ̄}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{ ́}
```

to make `biblatex` work.  What has caused this change?  Is there any way to make these lines conditional on the TeX Live version, so that my files are backward-compatible to my other machines which still have the old TeX version?

Note: a typical `.bib` entry of mine is

```
@book{Cederlof:stow,
   author=   {Mikael Cederl\"of},   
   title=    {The element \emph{-st\=ow} in the history of English},
   year=     {1998},
   series=   {Acta Universitatis Upsaliensis: Studia Anglistica
 Upsaliensia},
   publisher={Uppsala University},
   number=   {103},
}
```

The macron seems to require the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, but the umlaut does not.

Comment: You'll probably need to provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test.

Comment: For one of the issues or both?   It's a bit hard when I have several Mb of .bib files.   I thought the first issue might be a known one.

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0304}{ ̄}` may avoid an error but I doubt that it will give the right output. Your bib files contains something that doesn't work in a current latex/biblatex but without more info about the entries and the encoding of your files nobody can help you.

Comment: Thanks - I think it does give the right output, but I will double-check it.    But what about \nocite{*}? That's a separate issue and should not depend on encoding etc.

Comment: assuming that you use pdflatex: defining a combining accent can't work, pdflatex can't handle this.  So you should either get a lonely accent or nothing in such places. (You can use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0304}{XXXXXXXXX}`  to check where this is used). And regarding the nocite: You are processing all bib entries with it, and at least one of them breaks. This can have various reasons, including a wrong encoding.

Comment: U+0304 and U+0301 are the macron (over bar) and acute accents so if you make these empty you will certainly have corrupted your bibliography  text.

Comment: But did I make them empty?    All I did was respond to an error message from biblatex.   It told me exactly what \DeclareUnicodeCharacter command was needed.  I added this and the error message went away.   Sorry, I don't have access to the machine which has the problem today.   I will report more tomorrow.

Comment: Check the (next) entry at the point where `nocite` fails, for: missing or unbalanced braces; too many levels (3 or more) of nested braces. If you are using unicode fonts, then I would expect you to be compiling with xelatex\lualatex. Unrelated: with UTF-8 file encoding, you can type in the character(s) by codepoint or directly, so `a^^^^0304` typesets an `ā` (when using a uunicode font), as indeed does the pre-composed glyph `ā` itself. `ĕĥĵņŕŷą` , `Ѡѥѩѯѿ` etc

Comment: Can you verify that the entry `Cederlof:stow` shown in the question errors for you if you don't have any `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`s, please? I get no error from this particular entry even without any `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`s.

Comment: The TeX Live on your older system predated the LaTeX shift to UTF-8 standard encoding. Unless you specifically told LaTeX to use a different encoding you will have effectively been restricted to ASCII. In 2018 LaTeX switched to UTF-8. Since `biblatex` tries to detect your document encoding it will now try to use UTF-8. Usually this will work, but if you want to stick to ASCII, you could try passing the option `texencoding=ascii,` to `biblatex`. A similar approach would be to call Biber with the `--output-safechars` option as `biber  --output-safechars <filename>`.

Comment: As you say yourself, the `\nocite{*}` issue is a completely separate one and I would strongly encourage you to ask a separate question for that (see also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864), so that each question can focus on one thing and we don't get confused between two different issues.

Comment: I have found that adding --output-safechars to biber solves the fist problem -  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter is no longer needed. I knew about this option, but as some of my projects use latexmk, this option was not getting passed to biber in all cases.   Thanks to everyone for the help. \nocite{*} is still giving problems and I am working on it.

Comment: Alright. I've written up a quick answer for the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` issue. I suggest you edit your question to focus on the first question only and ask a new question once you have more details on the `\nocite{*}` thing. That way answers are going to be more specific and questions and answers are more useful for future visitors as well.

Comment: New question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636690/biblatex-nocite-causes-tex-capacity-exceeded.

Comment: I removed the `\nocite{*}` bit of the question since it has been transferred to a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The TeX Live on your older system predated the LaTeX shift to UTF-8 standard encoding (see, e.g. [`ltnews28`](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf)). Unless you specifically told LaTeX to use a different encoding you will have effectively been restricted to ASCII. In 2018 LaTeX switched to UTF-8.

Since `biblatex` tries to detect your document encoding it will now try to use UTF-8. Usually this will work, but if you want to stick to ASCII, you could try passing the option `texencoding=ascii,` to `biblatex`. A similar approach would be to call Biber with the `--output-safechars` option as `biber  --output-safechars <filename>`.

The example `.bib` entry shown in the question compiled fine for me with a current TeX distribution, but is possible that some definitions are not present in a slightly older distribution or that you have other entries that are still problematic. (There is a long-standing issue with dotless/dotted i: [Unicode -(U+301) error in biblatex, but not in main text: {\'{\i}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469555/35864) and linked posts.)

The definitions

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0304}{ ̄}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{ ́}
```

will most likely not do anything useful, since they redefine combining characters. pdfLaTeX cannot really deal with combining characters, so documents using this code might compile (I'm not even sure about that), but are most likely not going to look as expected.

It is probably better to try and use something like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0304}{XXXXXXXXX}` to find which entry causes the issue and to address that more directly by finding out why the combining accent is used.